# Ho do I fixe permission denied when trying to upload a file to my wordpress server using file zila

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api, filezilla

please can anyone help with a solution? am getting an error message that says permission denied anytime I try to upload files to my (LEMP) server using File Zila. I have tried changing the file permission in File Zilla to 777 but still does not work.

Answer (score -1):

if you have SFTP then follow below steps:

```
sudo chmod -R o+rw /var/www/html    /* Location for  folder or file */

chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/         /* Location for  folder or file */
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but I get another error: Operation not permitted

Comment: @DavidMaxwell because you haven't  SSH or SFTP access.Please check with Server and connect terminal and set permission with above command

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to give the {user} as well as the www-data both access to the website directory try this

//without {}

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data {userName}
```

#This adds user to www-data group

//set permissions for user group www-data

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/html
```

//followed by

```
sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www/html
```

this will enable {user} to use SFTP with the FileZilla or other programs to read and write files in the directory without sudo